# How to connect Mist to the private blockchain on remote server (Azure)?

Tags: azure, blockchain, ethereum

I've installed Mist on my local PC (Windows 10), but I don't want to sync Main/Test networks. So I've used this [Ethereum + Azure](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/uk_faculty_connection/2016/08/01/getting-started-with-blockchain-as-a-service-using-microsoft-azure-dev-test-labs/) tutorial and now I can work via SSH on my private network.

```
geth --dev console
```

More than that, I know that it's possible to run Mist on custom blockchain using special flag

```
mist.exe --rpc http://YOUR_IP:PORT
```

So, according to `geth --help`, I'm running `geth --dev --rpc console` on Azure's virtual machine, after that I'm running `mist.exe --rpc http://VM_IP:8545` and there is an error:

```
[2016-09-24 18:01:21.928] [INFO] Sockets/node-ipc - Connect to {"hostPort":"http://VM_IP:8545"}
[2016-09-24 18:01:24.968] [ERROR] Sockets/node-ipc - Connection failed (3000ms elapsed)
[2016-09-24 18:01:24.971] [WARN] EthereumNode - Failed to connect to node. Maybe it's not running so let's start our own...
[2016-09-24 18:01:24.979] [INFO] EthereumNode - Node type: geth
[2016-09-24 18:01:24.982] [INFO] EthereumNode - Network: test
[2016-09-24 18:01:24.983] [INFO] EthereumNode - Start node: geth test
[2016-09-24 18:01:32.284] [INFO] EthereumNode - 3000ms elapsed, assuming node started up successfully
[2016-09-24 18:01:32.286] [INFO] EthereumNode - Started node successfully: geth test
[2016-09-24 18:01:32.327] [INFO] Sockets/node-ipc - Connect to {"hostPort":"http://VM_IP:8545"}
[2016-09-24 18:02:02.332] [ERROR] Sockets/node-ipc - Connection failed (30000ms elapsed)
[2016-09-24 18:02:02.333] [ERROR] EthereumNode - Failed to connect to node Error: Unable to connect to socket: timeout
```

P.S. Mist version - 0.8.2

Comment: Question moved to http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8827/how-to-connect-mist-to-the-private-blockchain-on-remote-server-azure

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is correct. I would say that you have a network configuration issue that prevents your Mist to talk to geth.
I would suggest doing the following test and see if you run into the same issue:
- on the machine where you have Mist, find the geth.exe executable
- run geth with `geth --testnet  --rpc`
- start mist with `./Mist --rpc /.../Ethereum/testnet/geth.ipc` or `./Mist --rpc http://localhost:8545`

I am on a Mac so I guess you will have to reverse the / and add some C: decorations here and there.